# Adding together total completed words

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game there are different size words from 3-6. Once a certain amount of words are completed in the grid the rest of the grid fades away. I want it to add up all the word size varieties rather than just taking one in to consideration. For example I have it at the moment to fadeOut once two words are completed. The problem is it only fades when two, three letter words are complete or two four letter words are complete etc.

```
var completeLetters = $('.wordglow2').length;
var threeLetter = (completeLetters / 3);
var fourLetter = (completeLetters / 4);
var fiveLetter = (completeLetters / 5);
var sixLetter = (completeLetters / 6);


if (threeLetter == 2) {
    $('table').fadeOut(2000);
}
if (fourLetter == 2) {
    $('table').fadeOut(2000);
}
if (fiveLetter == 2) {
    $('table').fadeOut(2000);
}
if (sixLetter== 2) {
    $('table').fadeOut(2000);
}
```

Is there not a way of having a variable that combines all the words and then creating an if statement for that?

Comment: What is `$('.wordglow2')`? How do you think to determine the length of a word?

Comment: Ahh sorry. wordglow2 is the style added to a word when it is complted. @Bergi

Comment: Presumably $('.wordglow2') selects all letters that have been used by the player as part of the game. But there appears to be no way of determining what the actual words that these letters make up are...

Comment: When I make the variables "threeLetter" etc it divides the word up by the amount of letters in the word @El Ronnoco

Comment: Could you atleast post the HTML of one completed world with the `wordglow2` class. This might make the question easier to answer and avoid confusions for the people who are trying to help you.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/HZX6k/4/

Comment: I don't understand how you can tell if for example one 6-letter word has been created or two 3-letter words?

Comment: @sMilbz: Just another issue: You can easily cheat the game by selecting the invisible letters, which makes them readable :-)

Comment: I will prevent right click being made then or something @Bergi

Comment: No, just remove the letters from the drop zones @sMilbz

Comment: Can you show me what you mean? @Bergi

Comment: It seems that you are trying to determine the current state of the game from the markup/CSS classes etc. I would advise against this. You need to somehow track the game itself using a JavaScript object which allows you to easily see what is going on. It will make your code easier to read and more robust.

Comment: @Bergi Can you show me what you mean? I have tried but can't get it to work. Thanks

Comment: Just save the letters in the game state, and don't expose them in the DOM (or at least make them `display:hidden`). As soon as a word is to show up, you insert them or make them visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly - I would advise that you are doing this the wrong way - you are determining game state from the HTML/CSS representation of the game. I would recommend that you create an object which represents the game state and then use this object to determine the manipulations you need to make to the HTML/CSS representation. This will also make doing what you are trying to do here much easier.

For example you may end up being able to say something like...

```
if (gamestate.wordscomplete == 3) {//fade board//}
```

...which is a lot more pleasant than digging through the HTML. But I digress...

Ok so the class `wordglow2` gets added to a *letter* when it is correct. Each `<tr>` in the grid can contain a word. So...

```
function gamestate() {
  var words = []; //new array to store completed word counts
  var wordscompleted = 0; //overall word count
  //create an entry for 3,4,5, and 6 letter words
  for (var wc = 3; wc <=6 ; wc++) {words[wc] = 0;}

  $('table.tablestyle > tr').each( function(i,el) {
    // get the number of complete letters in this row
    var wordlength = $(el).find('.wordglow2').length; 
    if (wordlength >=3 && wordlength <= 6) { 
      // a completed word should not be outside of this range anyway
      words[wordlength]++; //increment the appropriate counter
      wordscompleted++; //increment overall counter
    }
  });
  //return a gamestate object 
  return { wordscompleted : wordscompleted , words : words };
};
```

The above function will look at each row in the game table and count the number of `wordglow2` cells. If this is between 3 and 6 then an overall counter is incremented and also counter for each word length is incremented.

It can be used as follows...

```
var gs = gamestate();

gs.wordscompleted //total words completed
gs.words[3]       //total 3-letter words completed
gs.words[4]       //total 4-letter words completed etc etc
```

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/HZX6k/6/

This fiddle just uses a global object to track the gamestate incrementing the count and the count for each of the 3,4,5,6 letter count words as it goes.

Comment: This is great, do you have a fiddle? @El Ronnoco

Comment: Yes http://jsfiddle.net/7h5JZ/2/. I have added a simple `alert` of word count after completion of each word. You will need of course to apply whatever game logic you require.

Comment: Oh and it looks to me like Lion=Cat and Bear=Dog :D

Comment: Just realised on playing a bit more that you can have more than one word on a line... So this gamestate code will not work as it assumes one word per `<tr>`

Comment: Well we are back to my original point of it not being a good method to determine game-state from markup! You will need to declare a gamestate variable which you update as the words are completed.

Comment: It doesn't let me skip to next word though now. @El Ronnoco

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16817/discussion-between-el-ronnoco-and-smilbz)